How can I make the design on the base of my 3d scythe model?
I am a newbie who only knows some basics of blender and currently trying to learn it.
I have first tried to make a dagger and after some tries made this (my first 3d model):

And currently I am trying to make a scythe from this image:

And what I made so far is:
I want to make those lines as design on the base of my scythe blade which I want to be extended inside of it and make it look better rather than plain, here's what it currently looks like:

How can I make it like the reference image?
